# pandas get timestamp difference in milliseconds as integer

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

How can I get the millisecond difference between these two timestamps in pandas as an integer?

My attempt so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


ts1 = datetime(2018, 1, 1, 22, 36, 9, 38000)
ts2 = datetime(2018, 1, 1, 22, 36, 7, 908000)


df = pd.DataFrame("ts1": [ts1],"ts2": [ts2]})


df['interval_ts'] = df['ts1'] - df['ts2']

df['interval_ts'] = df['interval_ts'].apply(lambda x: x.microseconds / 1000)
```

My expected output is: 1130

Comment: @FilipeAleixo it gives out 130 instead of 1130..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), multiple by `1000` and cast to integer:

```
df['interval_ts'] = ((df['ts1'] - df['ts2']).dt.total_seconds() * 10**3).astype(int)
```

Or convert to native numpy format and divide `10**6`:

```
df['interval_ts1'] = ((df['ts1'] - df['ts2']).astype(np.int64) / 10**6).astype(int)
print (df)
                      ts1                     ts2  interval_ts  interval_ts1
0 2018-01-01 22:36:09.038 2018-01-01 22:36:07.908         1130          1130
```